# group by min and max date

Tags: sql, ms-access, gaps-and-islands

```
date        |  name      | go to work 
------------+------------+---------
02/01/2012  | Mike       |  train
03/01/2012  | Mike       |  train
04/01/2012  | Mike       |  bus
07/01/2012  | Mike       |  bus
08/01/2012  | Mike       |  bus
09/01/2012  | Mike       |  train
```

With these record I want create a table:

```
name     from        to              go to work 
------------------------------------------------
Mike     02/01/2012  03/01/2012        train
Mike     04/01/2012  08/01/2012        bus
Mike     09/01/2012  09/01/2012        train
```

I do not know how write SQL code in Access.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: It might be good to know what version of access you have.  Also, what OLAP functions are present, or are we going to have to do this the 'hard' way?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name, MIN(`date`) AS from, MAX(`date`) AS to 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name, go_to_work
```

Comment: For one, it is riddled with unescaped reserved words.

Comment: with yuor query the result is

Comment: the result is not that i want because train is from 2/1/2012 to 9/1/2012 and i want 3 record in output list

Comment: xdazz - Check the desired results again - the OP wants windowed results, not 'strict' min/max dates for travel method (which he also needs listed).